# rails update and create 2 models in one form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for, nested-form-for

I am using rails cast 196 ( http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true ) to help me on my project, I am trying to modify the code so that when I make a new question, I am able to change the survey's title in the form. right now the form submits but no change is made to the Survey's title in the db

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end
```

I moved the accepts_nested_attributes_for from the Survey to the Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey
end
```

I added the :title (the field that I want to modify) in the questions pramas

```
def create
    @question = Question.new(question_pramas)
end

def question_pramas
    params.require(:question).permit(:content, survey_attribute: :title)
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :surveys do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :title %>
    <%= builder.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  ...
```

Comment: Is the problem happens while creating or updating?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to change your question_prams method to specify "survey_attribute**s**".

```
def question_pramas
  params.require(:question).permit(:content, survey_attributes: [:title])
end
```

Comment: Could you share the post / put parameters from the server log?

Answer (score 1):

To further `Tom Fast`'s answer, you'll also need to get your associative names sorted properly:

```
<%= f.fields_for :survey do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :title %>
    <%= builder.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>

#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:content, survey_attributes: [:title])
   end
end
```

Comment: the text field is not visible anymore when i change  :surveys to :survey